# Regex HTML Mismatch

Tags: html, regex

So I am trying to use the following regex in an HTML input:

```
<input ... pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9\-.,&?!@#~\';+_ ]+$" ... >
```

Yes, it's a pretty basic way of setting up a whitelist, and yes, it isn't exactly pretty to look at. However, at the very least it works on regex101.com, so I figured it would be fine to use. Unfortunately, I get the following error:

> Pattern attribute value ^[a-zA-Z0-9-.,&?!@#~\';+_ ]+$ is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[a-zA-Z0-9-.,&?!@#~\';+_ ]+$/: Invalid escape

How am I able to check so that what is acceptable on a website like regex101.com matches what is acceptable in an HTML page?

Comment: To figure a literal backslash, you need to escape it (with an other backslash). You get this error message because the escape sequence `\'` doesn't exist. Also you can avoid to escape the hyphen if you put it at the end of the character class. To finish, you don't have to put anchors `^` and `$` in a pattern attribute because they are implicit.

Comment: So, does the error come from the _engine_ or does it come from the _parser_ ?